# PHP how to get the exact argv (exact params to current command)?

Tags: php, shell, argv

The $argv array contains *almost* same values and I can't find who holds the exact ones. I mean all escaping/enquoting of special symbols disappear. And thus I can't pass same params to another script (or simply log exact command called) without re-processing which is a useless code I'd like to avoid.

Here's a test php file:

```
<?php
var_dump($_SERVER["argv"]);
```

Demonstration:

```
[denis@mypc ~]$ php test.php key="val space" key2=val\ space
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(8) "test.php"
  [1]=>
  string(13) "key=val space"
  [2]=>
  string(14) "key2=val space"
}
```

So if I then use join(" ", $argv) I will get:

```
test.php key=val space key2=val space
```

Which is not the same call (contains 4 parameters, not 2).

Again: ideally I need to get exactly same command I'm executing in.

Comment: You already get exactly what PHP sees. Escapes are processed by the shell, before PHP ever sees them.

Comment: Why do you use key=value pairs instead of using getopt-style arguments like people would expect from a commandline script?

Comment: See this function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.getopt.php

Comment: I do use getopt (longopts) in further script I'm trying to proxy all params. Anyway, will it solve the issue? If it will be "test.php -k val space -k2 val space" will getopt() return 2 args, not 4 or more?
And is longopt considered a bad manner?

Comment: With longopts I'm getting more user-friendly params. E.g. --verbose --test --force instead of -vtf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have to process your arguments like this

```
$arguments = $argv;
array_shift($arguments);
foreach($arguments as $value) {
    $pieces = explode('=',$value);
    if(count($pieces) >= 2) {
        $real_key = $pieces[0];
        array_shift($pieces);
        $real_value = implode('=', $pieces);
        $real_arguments[$real_key] = $real_value;
    }
}
```

the array `$real_arguments` contains the processes values

Comment: Thanks, I'd like to avoid such complicated logic, AFICS it tries to guess/fix params, with low mistakes level, no guarantee they are exactly same. Another side of coin is that I need this in 2 different projects connecting to each other, having no common codebase. So would like to find a minimum number of lines/logic to duplicate. Just in case, I do use getopts() at the end.

Comment: Ok, if no other sollution will use this :)
just what is missing - "else" for flags without = (e.g. --verbose)